# MySQL GROUP BY column and COUNT another column conditionally in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am trying to query a table `reviews` from a MySQL database. Each row represents a review made on a product. The data for the relevant columns is stored like this:

```
{ product_id: 25, rating: 1, recommend: 'false' },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 4, recommend: 'true' },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 3, recommend: 'true' },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 2, recommend: 'false' },
{ product_id: 25,  rating: 1, recommend: 'false'}
```

I need to get the total of each type of rating (eg. how many reviews gave it a ‘1’), and then count how many reviews have recommend ‘true’ and how many have recommend ‘false’. I would like the query to return data like this:

```
{ product_id: 25, rating: 1, total: 2, recommendTrue: 2, recommendFalse: 3},
{ product_id: 25, rating: 2, total: 1, recommendTrue: 2, recommendFalse: 3},
{ product_id: 25, rating: 3, total: 1, recommendTrue: 2, recommendFalse: 3},
{ product_id: 25, rating: 4, total: 1, recommendTrue: 2, recommendFalse: 3},
```

Technically I don’t need the recommendTrue and recommendFalse to be on every line, but because I am grouping by the type of rating, the redundancy is fine.

When I use this query (A):

```
'SELECT product_id, rating, COUNT(rating) as total'
' ' + 'FROM reviews' 
' ' + 'WHERE reviews.product_id = ?' 
' ' + 'GROUP BY rating' 
' ' + 'LIMIT 50'
```

I get back part of the desired result:

```
{ product_id: 25, rating: 1, total: 1 },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 3, total: 1 },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 2, total: 3 },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 5, total: 1 },
{ product_id: 25, rating: 4, total: 2 }
```

I now need to count the total number of True and False recommends amongst all the reviews for product_id 25.

I am trying this query (B):

```
"SELECT r.product_id, COUNT(r.recommend='false') as F, COUNT(r.recommend='true') as T"
" " + "FROM reviews AS r"
" " + "WHERE r.product_id = ?"
" " + "GROUP BY r.rating"
" " + "LIMIT 50"
```

And getting this result:

```
{ product_id: 25, F: 1, T: 1, rating: 1, total: 1 },
{ product_id: 25, F: 1, T: 1, rating: 3, total: 1 },
{ product_id: 25, F: 3, T: 3, rating: 2, total: 3 },
{ product_id: 25, F: 1, T: 1, rating: 5, total: 1 },
{ product_id: 25, F: 2, T: 2, rating: 4, total: 2 }
```

The recommends need to be counted separately for True and False but should not be counted separately for rating. The way I am writing it, it is counting ALL the recommends (true and false) per rating.

Comment: Instead of `COUNT(r.recommend='false') as F` try `SUM(CASE WHEN r.recommend='false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as F`.

Comment: *The data for the relevant columns is stored like this* This value is not correct for MySQL. Provide this as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts for unambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate queries: one for the true/false and one for the ratings.

You can combibe the two with a join statement. The query in the join will calculate the true/false and then the result is combined with the ratings query:

```
select product_id, rating, count(*), t, f
from reviews 
  join (
    select 
      sum(if(recommend='true', 1, 0)) as t, 
      sum(if(recommend='false', 1, 0)) as f
    from reviews
    where product_id=?
  ) as q
where product_id=?
group by product_id, rating, t, f
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rAn8C6yjgr5T37GCXw3Cru/0).

Comment: Thank you so much ! This worked perfectly. I just had to remember to write the query args like this :
 `queryArgs = [productId, productId]` 
so that there would be one for each `?`
Thank you again for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on MySQL 8+ that supports window functions, you can try with `SUM() OVER ()` function for the base query, then make that as a subquery to do the `COUNT()` and grouping. Something like this:

```
SELECT product_id, rating,
       COUNT(product_id) AS total,
       recommendTrue,
       recommendFalse
FROM
(SELECT product_id, rating,
       SUM(recommend='true') OVER () AS recommendTrue,
       SUM(recommend='false') OVER () AS recommendFalse
FROM reviews r
WHERE r.product_id = '25') A
GROUP BY product_id, rating, recommendTrue, recommendFalse
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48c6a201f4cef856104a7b61173f75ac)